# Problema con relacion ManyToMany Laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6

Estoy trabajando las tablas presupuesto y prestaciones, con el objetivo de al añadir prestaciones al presupuesto, las guarde con su respectivo precio. 
Para esto, hice la relación BelongsToMany, entre los modelos. Estoy probando con tinker y me apareció este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Bueno, según la descripción del error, añadí valores por defecto a los campos presta_valor y cantidad (0 y 1 respectivamente).
Pero mi problema es que, al guardarse en la db, no me está trayendo el el precio de la prestación que añado al presupuesto.
Así se guarda en la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá está el código donde relaciono mi modelos
Presupuesto.php
public function prestaciones()

```
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Prestacion::class)
        ->using(PrestacionPresupuesto::class)
        ->withPivot(['presta_valor', 'cantidad']);
}
```

Prestacion.php

```
public function presupuestos()

{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Presupuesto::class)
        ->using(PrestacionPresupuesto::class);
}
```

Modeo PrestacionPresupuesto.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PrestacionPresupuesto extends Pivot
{
    //
}
```

Será que estoy haciendo mal la relación?. o hay otra forma de tratar este modelo?

Espero me puedan echar una mano. Gracias
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

leyendo  un poco sobre el error, mas o menos puedo entender de que va y puede que error va por la nomenclatura que es usada en español cuando por lo general se usa en ingles.

Puedes omitir el uso de "using" y tu relación de

**Presupuesto >> Prestación**

mas o menos iría así

```
public function prestaciones()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Prestacion::class, 'prestacion_presupuesto', 'presupuesto_id', 'prestacion_id')
        ->withPivot(['presta_valor', 'cantidad']);
}
```

el nombre de la tabla pivote se llama "prestacion_presupuesto" según el error de tu primera captura

esto con base a la parte de la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Un pequeño detalle es que tu tabla pivote tiene información adicional que son los campos "presta_valor" y "cantidad", para esto necesitas pasar esa información adicional.

Tu proceso en tinker es primero crear tu "Prestación" y después enlazar a "Presupuesto", en este momento ya conoces el id del presupuesto por lo que al ahcer attach sería de esta forma

```
$presu->prestaciones()->attach($prestacion1->id => [
    'presta_valor' => 0,
    'cantidad' => 1
]);
```

ahora el otro escenario que no sepas el "id" de la prestación y solo deseas agregarla ...

```
$prestacion = new Prestacion($attributes_from_request);
$presu->prestaciones()->save($prestacion, [
    'presta_valor' => 0,
    'cantidad' => 1
]);
```

claro está que los valores de 'presta_valor' y de 'cantidad' puedes establecerlos a tu gusto

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Jaime. Apliqué los cambios, pero llego a lo mismo que tengo. me guarda la prestación en el presupuesto, sin el precio.
Seguiré buscando.
Saludos